# How to access drawrect method from UIViewController?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, xcode4.2, drawrect

I am using Xcode 4.2 and have a UIViewController representing one of the scenes.

In it, inside `viewWillAppear` i have

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: FramesPerSecond target:self 
selector:@selector(gameLoop) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Inside `gameLoop` method, i have

```
[[self view] setNeedsDisplay];
```

**Problem:**

`drawRect` method is not being called (As i understand it it should be called from `setNeedsDisplay`

**Question:**

- Is it possible to define `drawRect` method inside a `UIViewController` class and is so how should one declare it? It is called on a `UIView` as i understand it.
- If is it not possible, how would you address the situation using Xcode 4.2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You would need to subclass the UIView that the UIViewController controls.

(As a side note, timers aren't great for game loops because you don't get totally predictable timing.)

Comment: Doesn't make that much difference where you create your timer, that seems like a plausible place.